# How do I see how much data I have used out of my free 20 gig on Parse

Tags: parse-platform

I have been trying to figure out how I can see how big the data in my Parse app is.
I cannot seem to find anything in the dashboard to say I have used x of the 20gig allowed.
Can anyone tell me where to look?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I finally found it.
I went to Account -> Billing -> Current Statement -> Preview

This gives you a list of all your Apps. You can then click the name to see the File Storage and Database Storage as well as all the other relevant details.

Hopefully this answer will help others who have a similar question in the future as it wasn't very obvious/clear to find.

Thanks